# XPATH - get all inner nodes except a particular one

Tags: xpath

this is my HTML

```
<book>
 <div id="name"></div>
 <span id="age"></span>
 <p id="contact_number"></p>
 ...
 ... 
 (more attributes)
</book>
```

I need to extract all the `text()` inside `<book></book>` except the `p` with `id="contact_number"`

so basically i need `//book//text()` except `//book//p[@id="contact_number"]//text()`

How can i do this in a single xpath query?

Comment: Well in your posted sample you have an empty `<p id="contact_number"></p>` so I don't see what you want to exclude. Other than that with XPath 2.0 your verbal description can be written literally `//book//text() except //book//p[@id="contact_number"]//text()`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen wow, that's a coincidence :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a better way if you can put the requirement differently. Anyway, to answer the question the way it asked, you can try this :

```
//book//text()[not(ancestor::p/@id='contact_number')]
```

or maybe just use `parent::p` instead of `ancestor::p` :

```
//book//text()[not(parent::p/@id='contact_number')]
```

add `[normalize-space()]` at the end if you need to filter out empty text nodes.

Comment: you're like an XPATH guru... Do you have a suggestion for a good  XPATH learning resource?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
//*[not(self::p[@id = 'contact_number'])]/text()[normalize-space()]
```